# Modx getResources: display all resources' ids

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, getresource, modx-chunks

I need to display all resources' ids as page content, so I used:

```
 [[!getResources? &parents=`0` &tpl=`myTpl`]]
```

and in myTpl chunk: `[[*id]],`

But it only displays the current resource's id five times like this:

```
63, 63, 63, 63, 63,
```

5 is the number of published resources I have in my tree. I guess my chunk is wrong. The question is how to display all resources' ids on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change [[*id]] to [[+id]].
[[*id]], [[*pagetitle]], etc. are placeholders for the current resource.